# Modal not showing up correctly in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to accomplish a cool modal that slides down onto the page.  I ran into a problem and do not know what it could be, but when I click the button the modal isn't being loaded at all even though the #CmapModal shows up in the url.  Any idea as to why the modal is not displaying when I click it?

Code for modal:

```
 <p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#CmapModal" class="btn btn-default"><b>View Map &raquo;</b></a></p>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="CmapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CmapModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            ...
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Try setting data-target instead of href, as in [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this with only CSS and HTML.

Here is a working solution for you: http://jsfiddle.net/H4SDk/

I have added a short javascript code:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).toggle("slow");
});
```

*You can change the ID names yourself.*

If I understood correct you just wanted the modal to show, right?

Comment: People often prefer doing the GUI related stuff through declarative code (HTML and CSS) and not using JavaScript when possible. It makes the markup cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the class "hide" in your model `div`. Try this;

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="CmapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="CmapModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/W5Cc3/1/)